# WCF IIS hosted service launch Process issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis, iis-7

On job, we are creating a "remote" build application. I mean, we are developing an application which need to build another application using Visual Studio Express.

So for this, we create a WCF Service hosted on IIS, this service requires some parameters and then starts devenev to build an executable and send them to a certain client.

Something like this:

```
public bool Generate(Configuracion configuracion, bool updateSvn, string usuario, string ip, string macAddress, string pcName) {
    try {
        ExecutionRequestRepository.GetInstance().AddRequest(new Model.ExecutionRequest() { 
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            LoggedUser = usuario,
            RequestUserIp = ip,
            RequestMacAddress = macAddress,
            RequestPcName = pcName,
            UpdateFromSvn = updateSvn,
            RequestExecName = configuracion.Nombre
        });
        bool resultado = false;
        foreach (Configuracion cfg in GetAll()) {
            cfg.Estado = false;
            UpdateConfiguracion(cfg);
        }
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data");
        string configFilePath = Path.Combine(path, "config", "RutaSolucion.txt");
        string solutionContaNet = string.Empty;
        TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(configFilePath);
        solutionContaNet = txtReader.ReadLine();
        txtReader.Close();
        configuracion.Estado = true;
        if (UpdateConfiguracion(configuracion)) {
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(solutionContaNet, "Solucion ContaNet ERP.sln"))) {
                string buildCommand = string.Format("/build Release \"{0}\"", Path.Combine(solutionContaNet, "Solucion ContaNet ERP.sln"));
                ProcessStartInfo psInfoDevEnv = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psInfoDevEnv.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com";
                psInfoDevEnv.Arguments = buildCommand;
                psInfoDevEnv.CreateNoWindow = false;
                psInfoDevEnv.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                psInfoDevEnv.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psInfoDevEnv.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process pDevEnv = new Process();
                pDevEnv.StartInfo = psInfoDevEnv;
                pDevEnv.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                pDevEnv.OutputDataReceived += (sender4, e4) => {
                    logger.Info(e4.Data);
                };
                pDevEnv.Exited += (sender3, e3) => {
                    resultado = true;
                };
                pDevEnv.Start();
                pDevEnv.BeginOutputReadLine();
                pDevEnv.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        return false;
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        return false;
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        return false;
    }

}
```

So with this we send the command to build the application, but allways get this message :

```
**The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created.**
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the user account the service is running under have the correct rights to read/write ?

Comment: I assume so, but depends on what folder should I aim for assigning permissions. Where is the Application Data folder for Visual Studio?

Comment: I would make sure the service account has read/write on the project folder for the solution. Sure you want to reinvent the wheel and not just you a build server? CruiseContol.NET is free and has api

Comment: I grantt access to all files and folder on the solution directory, but still getting the same.